# Is there any real-time task set which includes WCET on both CPU and FPGA for every task?

Tags: fpga, cpu, time

As it has been proven, every task (application) we can run on a CPU we can also run on an FPGA (even if that is just by building a soft CPU). In addition, there is not any rule (or relationship) between S/W Execution Time (executable on CPU) and H/W Execution Time (executable on FPGA) of a specific task.

Therefore, my very important question is that if there is a especial real-time task set (or benchmark) for a such hybrid platform containing CPU and FPGA in which the Worst Case Execution Time on CPU and FPGA is given for every task?

For example, a real-time task T1 = (SE,HE, D) and SE=Software Execution Time, HE=Hardware Execution Time and D=Predefined Deadline.

Comment: hm, you take the instruction set manual of your CPU. You find the complexity of the let's say integer multiplication. You build the same funtionality in FPGA, prove that you've got the highest throughput implementation, and look how long that takes? The number will be utterly meaningless, because after that, you either got the result in some CPU register, or in any part of the FPGA, but you're looking for arbirtray, meaningless results, as far as I can tell.

Comment: This looks a lot like the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the thing you do that would benefit from the knowledge of such a SE,HE tuple? And consider this: Since you claim to be dealing with an arbitrarily large FPGA (otherwise, you couldn't claim that everything doable on a CPU can be done in FPGA, you either need arbitrarily much silicon complexity or arbitrarily much memory for that), you could just 1:1 implement the same CPU in FPGA. And then your question is answered by "you get that for all software tasks; simply the factor between clocks in 'native' CPU and FPGA. Done."

Comment: I need such task set having SE and HE because I need to test my scheduling technique which is for that hybrid platform. On the other hand, random generating of task sets with random WCET (both on CPU and FPGA) doesn't appear reasonable.

Comment: that's a very interesting use case! However, you'd really need to first find tasks that actually *have* an implementation on the FPGA side and do "attach" to your scheduler, ie. whose results can be used (probably by software) after execution and include the "domain transfer" overhead (ie. memcpy if necessary, "done" interrupt handling / polling, etc). So, I'd start with benchmarking what you actually have, instead of benchmarking what FPGA designs there actually might be.

Answer (score 2):

The question is meaningless on several levels.

First, why would a high-level system design have different task execution time requirements that depend on the implementation technology? Either each task gets executed in the required time, or it doesn't.

Second, when you assign a task to hardware (FPGA), you generally dedicate a block of logic to that task. That block is either working on that task or sitting idle, so there's no reason to "schedule" it. What does your "hybrid scheduler" actually do?

In my experience, FPGA + CPU combinations are used either to implement things on the FPGA that simply cannot be done on the CPU, or to accelerate things on the FPGA that are inefficient on the CPU, such as signal processing (video, graphics, radar, etc.) or network processing (packet routing, etc.). Generally speaking, you design the FPGA implementation so that the FPGA itself is not the bottleneck on throughput — i.e., it can keep up with the "wire speed", whatever that might be in the particular application.

Comment: Heterogeneous processing environment usually is considered as a set of General Purpose Processors(GPPs) in which every processor has a different computation capacity. In this case, I assume a heterogeneous Processing Elements(PEs) containing GPP & FPGA. Now, the major problem is to decide which task must be run on which PE in different times. It depends on many conditions(e.g. make span). As it is noted in the literature, different task models can be considered. One says there are two versions(HW & SW) for every task. Regarding the conditions, scheduler decides to assign a task to CPU or FPGA.

Comment: I also must add that in a different task model, a given task set contains real-time tasks and every task is dedicated to run on either CPU or FPGA. Sadly, I couldn't find a such benchmark either. I mean a benchmark or task set that contains two types of tasks: Those which must run only on CPU (with WCET on CPU) and those which must run only on FPGA (with WCET on FPGA).

Comment: These kinds of details need to be in your question in order to narrow its focus. As it is, it is far too vague and broad because you've specified far too little about how you're actually using the FPGA(s). For example, if you're dynamically reconfiguring them for each task, the scheduler needs to account for the overhead of reconfiguration. I can't imagine that there's any kind of "standard benchmark" for the vague system (or application) that you've outlined so far.

Comment: Yes Exactly. In addition to WCET, configuration delay and required config area (number of CLBs) for configuring every task on FPGA must be known priory. As you said, what I meant by FPGA is generally Partially RunTime Reconfiguration Device (PRTRD). So you confirmed that there is no any standard benchmark for such system. This makes my work too difficult!

Comment: FPGAs are usually programmed to meet some defined timing constraint (This pin transitions at least 0.80 ps before that clock, and that pin must meet a setup time of XX ps and a hold time of at least YY ps at the device on the other end of a net having an electrical skew from the clock of ZZ ps), AND THE TOOLS WILL ENFORCE THIS.

Benchmarks really make no sense in this space, either the logic you have designed meets timing or it does not, and the timing analyser will tell you if it will work in a post place and route analysis pass.

Comment: @DanMills: I think you're straying away from the point. Using the soft CPU as an example, you can know that it meets its hardware timing constraints without knowing how long it will take to execute various software tasks. A CPU is just one specialized form of state machine; the same thing can be said about many other kinds of state machines.

Comment: @DaveTweed Indeed, but then you are back to classical WCET in a parallel machine with some (probably considerable) reconfiguration overhead. In my view, given you have a hard IP CPU already (Which is a better big gnarly state machine then the FPGA will ever be), the interesting case here is usually using the FPGA for dataflow type stuff which is usually fairly close to deterministic. For that sort of work flow could you not model as something like X clocks per input with an output latency of Y clocks, and model how those numbers changing interacts with the scheduler?